# Good online forum to ask DAW-related questions?

Tags: daw

I'm looking for a good forum where I could ask DAW-related questions, which can't be answered here (such as advice on commercial plugins, audio recording techniques, and so on). Would recommend any ? Ideally that would be a forum in which professional engineers participate.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, resource recommendations aren't [on topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. But I imagine the major DAWs (i.e. ProTools and Cubase) have their own communities.

Comment: https://gearspace.com/ and https://www.kvraudio.com/ may be of interest. Please note that questions relating to audio recording techniques will mostly be on topic here or on https://sound.stackexchange.com/ (or both); some questions regarding advice on plugins will also be on topic too, although not "what's the best x?" - type questions.

Comment: Agreed. For example, I’m always looking and asking on LogicProHelp which is really good.

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding why this question was closed. Every answer is always opinion-based (go ask any good jazz theory teacher if you're in doubt). I've posted dozens of questions in other forums of StackExchange and never have I experienced such toughness. I suppose the guidelines are too far from what I would expect this forum to be. Anyway, thank you very much for your advice @topomorto.

Comment: @GuitarExtended external resource requests including other sites to post questions are off-topic.